# Get current versions of applications via apt-get

Tags: debian, apt, application

apt-get install shows just really old versions of everything. E. g. "Eclipse Galileo" but currently it's "Juno" and imho there was "Helios" and "Indigo" in between. And gcc is 4.2 but I need at least 4.6 for c++11 features.

How can I get apt-get to show me new versions of the programs?

Comment: If you need new versions you might be better off using Debian's `sid`/`unstable` than the `stable` branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debian stable is exactly that, stable. It achieves this by using well tested software, "well tested" being synonymous with "used for a long time", usually backporting security fixes instead of updating to a new version once frozen. Debian stable isn't concerned with the latest and greatest software, it's concerned with being reliable.

If you want to have newer software, you probably want to check out the `testing` or `unstable` branches (most likely, the latter). You can change to unstable by following the instructions on the [Debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/InstallFAQ#Q._How_do_I_install_.22unstable.22_.28.22sid.22.29.3F).

Comment: Okay but aint it possible? I dont want gnome 3. But cant live without gcc 4.6++.What if i just [create](http://debgen.simplylinux.ch/) some source lists from wheezy and put them in to /etc/apt/sources.list?

Comment: @DevNoob Don't do that. You will seriously mess up your packages and package dependencies. You could quite easily bring your package management into an inoperable state. Best case: look for some backports.

Comment: @DevNoob  The Gnome team is proceeding with Gnome 3 and *discontinuing* Gnome 2.  You won't be able to stay with Gnome 2 forever, at least not if you want updates.  Eventually you will be forced to either accept Gnome 3 or choose something else (like a distro that supports Mate/Cinnamon).

Comment: @jw013 There is current discussion on the debian-devel list about adding support for Mate.

Comment: ... or possibly [backports](http://backports-master.debian.org/), though the selection of backported packages is fairly minimal.